# Print string X number of times without using loops or conditions

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I was asked this question and could not come up with a solution, hope to find it here.

We need a function that receives a number (X) and a string, it needs to print that string X number of times, without using any loops or if-else conditions.

It's more about a generic algorithm not a specific programming language.

My initial response was recursion, but it requires an IF clause.

```
func (int x, string namme)
{
    if(x>0)
    {
       print (name);
       func(x-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use recursion.

Comment: most people on SO are unwilling to help without you having provided examples of what you've tried.  I suggest discussing things you've already attempted

Comment: @theVoid my initial instinct was recursion, but even that needs an if-else statement to check for the base case

Comment: You can use recursion with ternary operator..

Comment: @theVoid, recursion would require an IF clause, I'm not aware of a recursion that does not involve an exist clause.

Comment: @Haris, What is a ternary operator?

Comment: That is a funny question :) You could write a two threaded program. Th1: does a recursive print(string) and sleep(1); Th2: does a sleep(number) and kill T1.

Comment: I think the answer depends on the programming language: there's no "generic algorithm". For example, there's solutions in C++, ruby, lambda calculus and prolog, but there's not much commonality across the solutions.

Comment: Logically, printing the string an infinite number of times would also print the string X times (it would also do other things). But this probably isn't the intent of your task.

Answer (score 4):

In general case, you cannot do that. Even recursion's terminal case requires condition. The only solution in such case is ... Template magic (surprise!)

Here is the solution:

```
template <int times>
void print(const string& str);

template <>
void print<0>(const string& str)
{
}

template <int times>
void print(const string& str)
{
    cout << str << " ";
    print<times - 1>(str);
}
```

Such approach requres from you compile time value of number of times. But result code will not contain any conditions (you can see asm code)

Example of usage:

```
print<5>("Yeah!");
```

Comment: I feel like a conditional is going to be executed at the machine level to determine which template the call to `print` matches

Comment: @Atreys, anyway this check will be performed at compile time. Generated code will not contain conditions. You can check asm code.

Comment: Nice! I was misunderstanding what was meant by "template". But this wouldn't be able to receive input from the user to print out X times... so close.

Comment: @atreys, exactly - it is the main drawback of such approach

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little trick in c++:

> **§4.7/4 (Integral Conversion)**
>
> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to one.

This means you can index an array using a boolean value. If your array contains function pointers you implemented an `if/else` statement.

```
void noop(int,std::string) {}
void print_n_times(int times, std::string text) {
    void (*next_function[])(int,std::string) = {
        noop,
        print_n_times
    };
    next_function[(times-1)>0](times-1, text);
    std::cout << times << ' ' << text << '\n';
}
```

See it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a084a5dab56024e3)

You can do the same thing in python:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 10 2016, 12:56:26) 
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def noop(times,text):
...     pass
... 
>>> def print_n_times(times,text):
...     next_function = [noop, print_n_times]
...     print(text);
...     next_function[int((times-1)>0)](times-1, text)
... 
>>> print_n_times(4, "Hello World!")
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete program demonstrating this.  I would not recommend writing anything like this in Real Life.

This takes advantage of the fact that subtracting 1 from 0 will set the most significant bit in an integer.  I shift bit 63 down to 0 to get either a 1 or 0 (i.e. to avoid a conditional) and call one of two functions.  runtime.Goexit will terminate a goroutine, but will call all deferred functions in the process.  This unlocks a mutex that lets the sillyString function terminate only after all of the prints have happened.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    sillyString("omg", 10)
}

func sillyString(s string, n int) {
    var m sync.Mutex
    m.Lock()
    go func() {
        defer m.Unlock()
        mustGoDeeper(s, uint64(n-1), []func(){runtime.Goexit, func() {}})
    }()
    m.Lock()
}

func mustGoDeeper(s string, n uint64, fs []func()) {
    sig := (1 - int(n>>63))
    fs[sig]()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s)
    mustGoDeeper(s, n-1, fs)
}
```

Comment: It looked at first like you were using Go, but you were really just using pseudocode.  Anyway this works in Go, but obviously isn't generally portable.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion looks like a good way to go, but we need to stop an infinite recursion.  That means being sneaky.  Using a `try ... catch` can do the job, at least in a language which supports that construct:

```
void printXtimes(String text, int x) {

    try {
        int z = 100 / x;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Zero divide so exit program.
        exit(0);
    }

    println(text);

    printXtimes(text, x-1);

} // end printXtimes()
```

That is a Java-like pseudocode.  In real Java the compiler gives a warning about infinite recursion, but it compiles and runs correctly, printing the text message the given number of times.  An interesting problem.